# JSON.stringify getting empty after second update request via ajax in spring mvc

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, spring

Im trying to make an update functionality using jquery ajax with json object. Obviously, i dont want the page to get refreshed every time I send a request in spring mvc controller. First I have a dataTable that holds the data and when the row was clicked i have to invoke the dialog together with the data on the respective row. The data we're then store in the json object and send it to server via ajax request then process it in a spring controller. Well, it works perfectly in first request but when I update/send second request (remember no page reload happened), I got the empty json object in JSON.stringify(jsonObj). Here's the code hope you guys could help. Thanks:

**.Js** This is the script that sends json request via ajax

```
$('.valuesTb')
            .on(
                    'click',
                    'tbody tr',
                    function() {


                        var vpType = "", vdescEn = "", vdescZh="", vsstartDate = "", veendData="" ;

                        var val = [];
                        var cnt = 0;
                        var valueId = $(this).find('input').val();
                        var $row = $(this).closest("tr"), // Finds the closest
                        // row <tr>
                        $tds = $row.find("td"); // Finds all children <td>
                        // elements

                        $.each($tds, function() { // Visits every single <td>
                            // element
                            cnt++;
                            // console.log($(this).text()); // Prints out the
                            // text within the
                            val[cnt] = $(this).text();
                            // console.log("val count value: " + val[cnt]);//
                            // <td>
                        });


                        $('#parentType').val(val[1]);

                        $('#desc_en').val(val[2]);

                        $('#desc_zh').val(val[3]);

                        $('#vStartDate').val(val[6]);

                        $('#vEndDate').val(val[7]);
                         alert("tdHiddenValue: " + valueId + "ptype"+$('#desc_en').val());

                        var dialog, form,

                        parentType = $('#parentType'), descEn = $('#desc_en'), descZh = $('#desc_zh'), vStartDate = $('#vStartDate'), vEndDate = $('#vEndDate'), allFields = $(
                                []).add(parentType).add(descEn).add(descZh)
                                .add(vStartDate).add(vEndDate), tips = $(".validateTips");

                        dialog = $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
                              autoOpen: false,

                              width: 350,
                              modal: true,
                              buttons: {
                                "Update":  function(){
                                    var urlpath = base_url + "/app/updateValueListDetails.do";


                                    var parentType = $('#parentType').val();
                                    var desc_en = $('#desc_en').val();
                                    var desc_zh = $('#desc_zh').val();
                                    var startDate = $('#vStartDate').val();
                                    var endDate = $('#vEndDate').val();

                                      var updateData = {
                                        "id" : valueId,
                                        "type" : parentType,
                                        "descEn" : desc_en,
                                        "descZh" : desc_zh,
                                        "startDate" : startDate,
                                        "endDate" : endDate
                                    };

                                      alert("  stringify: "+ JSON.stringify(updateData));

                                    console.log("From updateValues(): " + JSON.stringify(updateData));

                                    if (parentType != "" && desc_en != "" && desc_zh != ""
                                            && startDate != "" && endDate != "") {
                                        $.ajax({
                                            url : urlpath,
                                            type : "POST",
                                            contentType : 'application/json',
                                            data : JSON.stringify(updateData),
                                            async : false,
                                            cache : false,
                                            processData : false,
                                            success : function(resp) {
                                                console.log("success json: " + resp);

                                            },
                                            error : function() {
                                                console.log("error parsing json from server");
                                            }
                                        });

                                    }else{

                                        console.log("update cancelled");
                                    }


                                    showValuesPAge();
                                    event.preventDefault();
                                    dialog.dialog("close");
                                },
                                Cancel: function() {
                                  dialog.dialog( "close" );
                                }
                              },
                              close: function() {
                                form[ 0 ].reset();
                                allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
                              }
                            });

                        form = dialog.find( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
                              event.preventDefault();

                            });

                        $('#dialog-form').dialog("open");


                        var scriptUrlJqueryUi = base_url
                                + "/app/resources/js/jquery-ui.js";

                        $.getScript(scriptUrlJqueryUi, function() {
                            dialog.dialog("open");
                        });

                        console.log('success retrieval of values for update');
                    });
```

**Spring controller** A controller that accepts the request from client. I am able to parse the json here.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateValueListDetails", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    String updateValue(Model model, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, @RequestBody String json) {
        boolean isSuccess = false;
        logger.debug("json string: " +  json);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();


        try {

            ValuesListDTO reqValue = mapper.readValue(json, ValuesListDTO.class);
            ValuesListDTO vDto = new ValuesListDTO();
            vDto.setId(reqValue.getId());
            vDto.setType(reqValue.getType());
            vDto.setDescEn(reqValue.getDescEn());
            vDto.setDescZh(reqValue.getDescZh());
            vDto.setStartDate(reqValue.getStartDate());
            vDto.setEndDate(reqValue.getEndDate());

            isSuccess = this.valueService.updateValues(vDto.getId(), vDto.getType(), vDto.getDescEn(),
                    vDto.getDescZh(), vDto.getStartDate(), vDto.getEndDate());


        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems I found my mistake, it is in the " dialog.dialog("close");" which invokes the Close button function and thus resets the form (fom[0],reset())  . I dont know really but i think in runtime the var that i have set in the first place becomes null except the id after alerting the json object. After refactoring my script it works like hell lol. Here's the code:

```
$('.valuesTb')
            .on(
                    'click',
                    'tbody tr',
                    function(e) {

                        e.preventDefault();
                        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                        var dialog, form,
                        parentType = $('#parentType'), descEn = $('#desc_en'), descZh = $('#desc_zh'), 
                        vStartDate = $('#vStartDate'), vEndDate = $('#vEndDate'), 
                        allFields = $([]).add(parentType).add(descEn).add(descZh)
                                .add(vStartDate).add(vEndDate), tips = $(".validateTips");
                        var val = [];
                        var cnt = 0;
                        var valueId = $(this).find('input').val();
                        var $row = $(this).closest("tr"), // Finds the closest
                        // row <tr>
                        $tds = $row.find("td"); // Finds all children <td>
                        // elements
                        $.each($tds, function() { // Visits every single <td>
                            // element
                            cnt++;
                            // console.log($(this).text()); // Prints out the
                            // text within the
                            val[cnt] = $(this).text();
                            // console.log("val count value: " + val[cnt]);//
                            // <td>
                        });


                         $('#parentType').val(val[1]);

                         $('#desc_en').val(val[2]);

                         $('#desc_zh').val(val[3]);

                         $('#vStartDate').val( val[6]);

                         $('#vEndDate').val(val[7]);

                        var parentType = val[1];
                        var desc_en = val[2];
                        var desc_zh = val[3];
                        var startDate = val[6];
                        var endDate = val[7];

                        dialog = $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
                              autoOpen: false,

                              width: 350,
                              modal: true,
                              buttons: {
                                "Update":  function(){
                                    var urlpath = base_url + "/app/updateValueListDetails.do";

                                    var uPType = $('#parentType').val();
                                    var uDescEn = $('#desc_en').val();

                                    var uDescZh =  $('#desc_zh').val();

                                    var uStartDate = $('#vStartDate').val();

                                    var uEndDate = $('#vEndDate').val();

                                    //alert("For Update: ptype= "+uPType+"descEn= "+uDescEn);

                                      var updateData = {
                                        "id" : valueId,
                                        "type" : uPType,
                                        "descEn" : uDescEn,
                                        "descZh" : uDescZh,
                                        "startDate" : uStartDate,
                                        "endDate" : uEndDate
                                    };

                                     // alert("  stringify: "+ JSON.stringify(updateData));

                                    console.log("From updateValues(): " + JSON.stringify(updateData));

                                    if (parentType != "" && desc_en != "" && desc_zh != ""
                                            && startDate != "" && endDate != "") {
                                        $.ajax({
                                            url : urlpath,
                                            type : "POST",
                                            contentType : 'application/json',
                                            data : JSON.stringify(updateData),
                                            async : false,
                                            cache : false,
                                            processData : false,
                                            success : function(resp) {
                                                console.log("success json: " + resp);

                                            },
                                            error : function() {
                                                console.log("error parsing json from server");
                                            }
                                        });

                                    }else{

                                        console.log("update cancelled");
                                    }


                                    showValuesPAge();
                                     $('.ui-icon-closethick').trigger("click");
                                    event.preventDefault();

                                },
                                Cancel: function(e) {
                                    event.preventDefault();
                                    dialog.dialog( "close" );

                                }
                              },
                              close: function(e) {
                                  event.preventDefault();
                               // form[ 0 ].reset();
                                      $('#parentType').val("");
                                     $('#desc_en').val("");
                                      $('#desc_zh').val("");
                                     $('#vStartDate').val("");
                                     $('#vEndDate').val("");
                                allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
                                dialog.dialog( "close" );
                              }
                            });

                            form = dialog.find( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
                              event.preventDefault();

                            });

                        var scriptUrlJqueryUi = base_url
                                + "/app/resources/js/jquery-ui.js";

                        $.getScript(scriptUrlJqueryUi, function() {
                            $('#dialog-form').dialog("open");
                        });

                        console.log('success retrieval of values for update');

                    });
```